# Implementing a Java Annotation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dropwizard

I am implementing the dropwizard example application in Kotlin and have an issue implementing the DateRequiredFeature. The Java code code is as follows:

```
    @Provider
    public class DateRequiredFeature implements DynamicFeature {
        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext context) {
            if (resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(DateRequired.class) != null) {
                context.register(DateNotSpecifiedFilter.class);
            }
        }
    }
```

with the annotation defined as:

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public @interface DateRequired {}
```

For the Kotlin side I have for the feature:

```
    @Provider
    class DateRequiredFeature : DynamicFeature(){
        override fun configure(resourceInfo: ResourceInfo, context: FeatureContext) {
            if (resourceInfo.resourceMethod.getAnnotation(DateRequired::class.java) != null) {
                context.register(DateNotSpecifiedFilter::class.java)
            }
        }
    }
```

but is is not clear how to implement the corresponding `DateRequired` annotation so that `getAnnotation()` is valid. The (Java) signature for `getAnnotation()` is

```
public <T extends Annotation> T getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass)
```

**Note**

Looks like an IntelliJ bug, I need to explicitly import the annotation although it is in the same package:

```
...
import DateRequired

@Provider
class DateRequiredFeature : DynamicFeature {
    override fun configure(resourceInfo: ResourceInfo, context: FeatureContext) {
        if (resourceInfo.resourceMethod.getAnnotation(DateRequired::class.java) != null) {
            context.register(DateNotSpecifiedFilter::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

then all is well using standard Kotlin annotation `annotation class DateRequired`

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Do you want to recode the annotation to Kotlin?

Comment: I would like to implement `DateRequired` annotation in Kotlin so that the  call `resourceInfo.resourceMethod.getAnnotation(DateRequired..)` works.

Answer (score 4):

Implementing a annotation in Kotlin is simpler than in Java. The default  `RetentionPolicy` in Kotlin is [`RUNTIME`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.annotation/-annotation-retention/index.html#enum-values). The `FUNCTION`,`PROPERTY_GETTER` and `PROPERTY_SETTER` are mapped to Java's `ElementType.METHOD`, for example:

```
import kotlin.annotation.AnnotationTarget.*

@Target(FUNCTION, PROPERTY_GETTER, PROPERTY_SETTER)
annotation class DateRequired;
```

Secondly, I have also discovered you used a Java platform class `ResourceInfo` which returns a `java.reflect.Method` instance. It might return `null` resulting in `NullPointerException` in Kotlin. You must use the [NPE-lovers operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) `!!` before calling the `getAnnotation` method:

```
resourceInfo.resourceMethod!!.getAnnotation(DateRequired::class.java)
//                         ^--- force to call
```

Last, the `DynamicFeature` is an interface. implements an interface in kotlin you must remove the parentheses `()`:

```
@Provider
class DateRequiredFeature : DynamicFeature{...}
```

You can see more details about annotations [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html).

Comment: Yes, that is what I tried. I am unable to refer to the class of `DateRequired` in the `getAnnotation()` call.

Comment: @DavidSoroko it has reported any error? indeed, the kotlin annotation class is transformed to java `@interface` like as yours. maybe your logic wrong?

Comment: see my note, looks like an IntelliJ issue.

Comment: @DavidSoroko hi, how about it after using the `!!` operator?